# <Python Crash Course - Eric Matthes> Do we really need the super() function here, as shown by author?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, super

New to OOP in Python. Was going through the chapter on classes and inheritance in the book [Python Crash Course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593279280) by Eric Matthes. In the following excerpt from the **inheritance** section of the chapter...:

[image]

...the author:

1. first defines a **new __init__()** method for the child class ElectricCar (which is a subclass to Car as per definition), and which takes the exact same parameters as it's parent's `__init__()` method
2. Within ElectricCar's `__init__()` method the author used **super()** to access the Car superclass's `__init__()` method.
3. The Author then initiates the **my_tesla** object which is an instance of the child ElectricCar class and prints the return value from the superclass's `get_descriptive_name()` method to generate output:[image]

My question is **was it necessary to go through all these hoops to achieve this end?** When he could have just relied upon the default **implicit inheritance** as such...

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

class Car(object):
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, manufacturer, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes to describe a car."""
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Return a neatly formatted descriptive name."""
        long_name = f"{self.year} {self.manufacturer} {self.model}"
        return long_name.title()

    .
    .
    .

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""
    pass

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
```

...to get the same output?

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of PCC. The approach you described works as long as you don't want to do anything specific to electric car objects in the __init__() method. As soon as you do, you need to start using super(). For example, in one of the later sections we add a battery, and we initialize the battery size in __init__(). PCC aims at providing a clear introduction without trying to cover all use cases, so I chose to leave out that aspect of the default inheritance behavior. I am quite open to revising that section, if you have a suggestion for how to treat it better.